# subclipse/svn 1.8 - unable to add existing files to source control

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I recently had to do a re-install of Eclipse (4.3 Kepler), and re-installed PyDev (3) and Subclipse (1.8), and re-established the connection to our SVN repository. When I attempt to add a project or individual files to Version Control, I get this error:

```
Unsupported working copy format svn: This client is too old to work with the working copy at 'C:\PythonDev\Common' (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client.
```

The SVN client I'm now using (1.8) is later than the one that was used when these files were initially added to the SVN repository, so the error is weird. Assuming that the actual problem is that the format is from an older (not newer) client, I attempted to run **svn upgrade** but the docs for that command are unclear, and no matter what path I specify I either get errors that the "wc.db" is not found (but it's right where the error says it's trying to find it) and that the specified folder isn't the working copy root. If I instead specify the folder that IS the working copy root, I get no response at all from svn upgrade - no errors, and no indication that anything was upgraded, and I still can't add these projects/files to source control.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Subclipse that has support for SVN 1.8.  That is Subclipse 1.10.x.

See:  http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Comment: Thanks, Mark - that did the trick. For anyone else encountering this issue, the 1.10.x version of Subclipse is NOT (contrary to what it says on the page that your link points to) accessible via the Eclipse Marketplace - it seems only Subclipse 1.8 is available using that update mechanism. Installing via the "Install new software" option on the Help menu, using the Subclipse 1.10x update link that also is listed on that page did the trick.

Comment: Only one version can be in the Marketplace.  1.8.x is still the version because of the SVNKit library.  That is still in Beta release for SVN 1.8 support and a lot of Subclipse users rely on SVNKit as opposed to the default JavaHL.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the connector that you are using in eclipse under Windows->Preferences->Team->SVN and ensure that the 1.3x are NOT selected, select 1.8 (or the higher aviable).

The subeclipse (plugins) use the SVN connectors (the plugin installation install some of them) and most of the times the lower version is selected by default. In SVN 1.7 the organization of the meta-data (.svn) was changed and optimized and is not compatible with older versions

Comment: Thanks, Francisco - once I followed Mark's advice, the client is now showing as JavaHL (JNI) 1.8.4, so I think I'm good here now...

Answer (score 0):

You can see which version you require in the link below:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de

And on eclipse you can install the right subclipse by finding your versions link below:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Subclipse client upgrades for the specific version of svn, it does NOT mean the upgrades make it fully compatible with newer versions, looking at the first link will make things a lot clearer.